# best constant for renorming a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider an $n$-dimensional normed vector space $V$ with norm $p$. It is always possible to find a new norm $p'$ coming from an inner product and $p$ and $p'$ are comparable up to a factor $\sqrt{n}$. I am wondering if anything is known about the optimal constant (asymptotic behaviour in $n$) or a reference where this issue is discussed.

Comment: Can you precise comparable to a factor $\sqrt{n}$? Do you mean $p'\leq \sqrt{n}\;p$ and $p\leq \sqrt{n}\;p'$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is always an inner product norm within the  (multiplicative) Banach–Mazur distance  at most $ \sqrt{n}$ from the given norm. This theorem is [due to Fritz John](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid). It shows up in several contexts, including the [Banach-Mazur compactum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_compactum).